# ios8.3 bluetooth lost connection every 30s

Tags: ios, bluetooth

Recently, I develop a BLE app in iOS8.3.

But, I found a terrible question.

When I connect the BLE device with iPhone, almost every 30s, the connection is lost. After I restart the iPhone, the problem is disappear.

Who maybe explain this?

Thank all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

```
Try switching Airplane mode on for 30 seconds, then turn it off and try connecting again.
Try holding down the home button and the Sleep/Wake button until your device restarts.
Turn your router off for 30 seconds and then switch it on again.
Go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings and then setup your Wi-Fi, Bluetooth again.
Try chaining the channel on your router and check the rest of the settings.
Make sure that your router firmware is up to date.
Try a factory reset of your iPhone.
```

Comment: I restart iPhone, the problem was solved, but I want to know why.